# Heat vent found under dishwasher

Tags: hvac

So we purchased a brand new home in June 2016 and found the builder put a heat vent under the dishwasher. He explained it's pretty normal but after asking HVAC pro's, it isn't.

My question is, should I have a toe kick vent installed? The builder didn't even cut the floor opening for it, but it is installed under the house.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. A diagram of the vent and dishwasher location would be really helpful.

Comment: No, it is not normal. It is terrible and should be fixed for free. I'd call the Building Inspector and make them tell the contractor.

Answer (score 1):

He put it in the wrong place by mistake. I would make him  move it. You should not have to rig something to correct his mistake. You may not need the vent if there are other vents in  the kitchen. I would still have it changed since you paid for a correct job.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I have decided to disconnect the supply line and place some extra insulation in the void. Luckily the opening in the hardwood was not done so that was a good thing. I also decided to check the other toe-kick register under another cabinet and found they did not complete the work there either. a 90 degree diverter was supposed to be installed but wasn't so I had to do that too. The HVAC company that did the install will NOT be coming this spring to install the AC.

Comment: I was in the installation and service business for 40 years; Furnaces boilers duct work piping, etc... My recommendation : if you find a good contractor that does great work,  use only him regardless of the cost since he will always come back if any of his employees make a mistake or something is installed wrong. And never try to take advantage of him. That HVAC company will not have a good lasting future.