# Heat register under dishwasher

Tags: hvac

So we bought a new build and found a heat register is directly under the dishwasher. Where the hvac is completely I stalled, the hardwood floor has not been cut and register dropped in.

My question is, should I complete the project or disconnect the supply line? Is it also normal for this placement? The builder says yes.

Comment: That's a new one on me. Is the area where the DW is an exterior wall? Is it insulated?

Comment: Under as in the toe-kick space (in the room, but "under" it), or under as back out of sight under the counter and the bottom part of the dishwasher? If the former, please edit the question to detail your reasons for thinking this is a bad idea.

Comment: Asked and answered yesterday. http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/105216/heat-vent-found-under-dishwasher - Do you want differing answers to the same question scattered throughout Home Improvement SE? We don't.